# Add a "boolean" column to Symfony's generated admin

Tags: admin, symfony-1.4

I have a blog made with symfony 1.4. In the generated admin, I've added the column "has tags", by adding the following to `Content.class.php` :

```
public function getHasTags()
{
  $count = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tagging')
    ->createQuery('c')
    ->where('c.taggable_model = "Content"')
    ->andwhere('c.taggable_id = ?', $this->getId())
    ->count();

  if ($count > 0) 
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

This works, but the column only shows "1" for *true* and nothing for *false*. Can I set this new column as boolean, so that symfony will show the picture of a cross or a check mark ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `generator.yml`

```
fields:
  yourFieldName:
    label: Has link
    type: Boolean
```

Comment: Weird, it shows a checkmark when true, but still nothing when false.

Comment: true :-) If you want to change that, use partials instead.